# String index out of range: 9?

Tags: java

I tried to convert the string after coma "," to integer 
for example 
input
Sarah,49
output
49
and I want the output as an integer

```
NameandGrade = scan.nextLine();

length = NameandGrade.length();

coma=NameandGrade.indexOf(',');

String StrMarks=NameandGrade.substring(coma+1,length+1);

int Intmarks = Integer.parseInt(StrMarks);

System.out.println(marks);
```

I wrote that code but it shows me after run it

> String index out of range: 9

Comment: Read the documentation of `String#substring` and reconsider `.substring(coma+1,length+1)`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun yes I should write .substring(coma+1,length) thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why didnt you do like this?

```
String[] splitted = NameandGrade.split(",");
String name = splitted[0];
int grade = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
```

Comment: Showing an alternative solution is fine, but pointing out to the current error is even better. The purpose is to help OP to learn from his mistakes.

Comment: you wrote the problem. But this: String Intmarks = Integer.parseInt(StrMarks); also won't work.

Comment: @galovics  thank you, I did mistake when I rewrite it here, but I know my mistake, and thank you to add new information because I am a beginner on java.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look into the values of variable comma and length

```
comma = 5
length = 8
```

Also the signature of the method substring is

```
String substring(int beginIndex,int endIndex)
```

where Parametes 
Parameters:

```
beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive.
endIndex - the ending index, exclusive.
```

Also lets number the characters of the string to get a better picture of what is going on in this case

```
 Sarah,49
 01234567
```

Now as you can see we need to pass the second parameters in this case as the index of last char + 1 (because the it is exclusive). which in this case will be the index of char '9', which is 7.
But what you are passing is length + 1 = 9, which is greater than the the size of the string and results in `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. 
To correct is you need pass the value 8 (index of the last char + 1, because it is exclusive). which in this case would be = length.

So if you change length + 1 to length in the arguments to substring method it fill be fixed.